# Different app's UI depends of device (iPhone/iPad) compiled into single file

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode, ipad

I have got done app for iPad. Now I want to "convert/rewrite" this app into both iPhone and iPad(not universal - because some behaviors and views looks different in iPhone than in iPad. I tried use targets (copy needed classes, do changes) but it's creating two files (one for iPad one for iPhone). What I want to do is compile this in to one file and during runtime checking if it is iPhone and use UI and classes for iPhone, the same for iPad. Do U have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use autolayout for this. 
For the components which are entirely different you can always use different view and load them based on what device you are running on at runtime.

With XIBs I have once done it using xib names, suffix with _IPad and a common class method which would pick up the right XIB at runtime for iPhone or iPad. You can attach the references from different XIBs to same code file.

Comment: Couldn't I just copy code once again in to project i.e. in new target (due to I don't want rename all classes) and at the beginning choose with target should be executed?